# how to submit a dapp on solana

Tags: dapp

how to submit a dapp on solana?
My project runs on the IoTeX chain, a public chain compatible with EVM. How can I quickly deploy my project to the Solana chain? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Think this will be a bit more challenging. Solana works pretty different than Ethereum, but here are a my thoughts (maybe it helps :))...

My first Google gave me this: https://neonevm.org/, which seems to be a project that tries to mimic EVM compatibility on Solana, but I have never worked with it so I have no idea how well this works.

My second thought, would be to do a course called 60 days of Solana. It is focussed on teaching EVM developers, how they can develop for Solana: https://www.rareskills.io/solana-tutorial